# Is there any hardware requirements for Linux kTLS in nginx?

Tags: ssl, linux-networking, linux-kernel, tls-offloading

I've followed closely the manual on [NGINX blog](https://www.nginx.com/blog/improving-nginx-performance-with-kernel-tls/). This works flawlessly on my machine, with an AMD Ryzen PRO 4750G. The output for a 5GB file using `curl` on `https://localhost` is twice as fast with kTLS, which is neat.

I've duplicated the same configuration options on my server that has a much less powerful CPU ([Intel Atom D2550](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/65470/intel-atom-processor-d2550-1m-cache-1-86-ghz.html)), but the system doesn't want to use kTLS, there is nothing in the debug log. So I'm wondering if there is some hardware requirements in the CPU, undocumented? The [kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/networking/tls-offload.html) doesn't seem to mention any.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question properly then the issue isn't with the CPU but with the NIC in your systems - the NIC itself needs to support kTLS offload, not all do.

Comment: Yes, maybe, that's also an option. However, in my "local" test, it doesn't use the NIC, since it's on localhost, so it can only be bound to CPU features.

Comment: Well if it's on localhost then the CPU's performance becomes incredibly important - and a 4750G is a hell of a lot more performant than an Atom D2550 - that's the issue.

Comment: Yes, but if it wasn't clear enough: without kTLS on localhost, I got ~750MB/s. With kTLS on localhost, I've got 1200MB/s, and the debug log shows that it's used. It's not the case on my Atom, and I'm looking for a reason. But I'm about to test on my AMD 4750G with the real NIC (and not localhost)

Comment: I tested a connection from another client to my computer, and indeed, the kTLS benefit is here: the CPU is much less used on my AMD 4750G with kTLS.